# React render Epoch timestamp convert to am pm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp, epoch

I am doing a personal `React.js` project. I am fetching an API and one of the values it is an `Epoch timestamp`. I would like to render it as a human readable time like am/pm. The Epoch timestamp is render after a `map`. Below you can see the code:

```
{value.map((dog, c) => (
                  <div key={c}>
                    <div><b>Race name:</b> {dog.Venue}</div>
                    <div><b>Start time:</b> {dog.AdvertisedStartTime}</div>
```

`{dog.AdvertisedStartTime}` renders a number like: `1641079080000`. This numbers are a time in the future, for instance 1:30pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. First define a helper function to convert `Epoch` to desired locale and use it inside the map. The function could be

```
function convertEpoch(value) {
  if (!value) {
    return ''
  }
  const time = new Date(Number(value));
  if (isNaN(time.valueOf())) {
    return '';
  }
  return time.toLocaleString("en-US", { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", hour12: true });
}
```

And use it in your `map` like

```
{value.map((dog, c) => (
              <div key={c}>
                <div><b>Race name:</b> {dog.Venue}</div>
                <div><b>Start time:</b> {convertEpoch(dog.AdvertisedStartTime)}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vishnu, but it renders an empty string. Here is a codesandbox for you to see the whole code. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-2733x?file=/src/components/Itemdetails/index.jsx

Comment: Can you give me the json data that you got from the api?

Comment: Also put `convertEpoch` function outside `const ItemDetails` for good practice, why create the function again and again in a loop

Comment: In the codesandbox is a folder name "data" with all the data from the API mocked. Also, for instance one of the items has this: AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641069600000)/",

Comment: The value you pass to the function is a string, string will return `Invalid Value` if you try to convert to DateTime, you need to first convert it into a number like `const epoch = Number(value)` inside your convert funtion. Do it after you check `if (!value)` condition

Answer (score 0):

```
let yourTimestamp = 1641079080000, (any number)
date = new Date(yourTimestamp * 1000),
dateVal = [
  date.getFullYear(),
  date.getMonth()+1,
  date.getDate(),
  date.getHours(),
  date.getMinutes(),
  date.getSeconds(),
];
console.log(dateVal);
```

Note that : Hours - mins and seconds depend on the time zone of your operating system.
in different time zones it can be anything. Hence you can add the time zone offset to the time to create the GMT date:

```
let myDate = new Date();
date = new Date(timestamp*1000 + myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

Comment: Thanks Amin. But, how I do use that function when I dinamically render the Epoch timestamp as in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how we can get time very easy way.

let today= new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(today);

so you can try this one:

```
{value.map((dog, c) => (
          <div key={c}>
            <div><b>Race name:</b> {dog.Venue}</div>
            <div><b>Start time:</b> {convertEpoch(dog.AdvertisedStartTime.toLocaleTimeString();)}</div>
```

Comment: can you share my your API link. To fix this problem

Answer (score -1):

This is an example how we can get time very easy way.

let today= new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(today);
so you can try this one:

```
{value.map((dog, c) => (
          <div key={c}>
          {convertEpoch(dog.AdvertisedStartTime.toLocaleTimeString();)}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shahrukh, but it breaks the whole code